# Java repaint() is not working in jPanel class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, repaint

I want to repaint my jPanel everytime I call the method called `change()`. In this method I'm just changing my boolean variable `draw` and I call `this.repaint()`. To paint on panel works but if I click the button the line is still there but the line should be gone. After I call `repaint()` I can't reach the `paintComponent()` method. Why is the method `repaint()` not working properly?

Here is my code from the panel class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class testPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public boolean draw = true;

    public testPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 603, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 299, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw == true) {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 35);
        }
    }

    public void change() {
        draw = !draw;
        this.repaint();

    }

}
```

Edit, this is how I access the method `change()`:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    testPanel testPanel = new testPanel();
    testPanel.change();

}
```

Edit, how I add the jPanel to my jFrame:

```
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new testPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
...
```

Comment: additionaly use `revalidate`.

Comment: I still can't reach the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: Where do you add a button? Did you add an actionListener to the button?

Comment: The button is in an other jFrame class, the button just calls the method `change()`. The method works and the button too, the problem is `repaint()`.

Comment: could you include this class?

Comment: Yes, I already told you there are no issues calling the jPanel class. The painting works, the panel works just the repainting doesn't work.

Comment: There must be a problem in your jFrame class, because your testPanel works fine for me.

Comment: @ArcticLord same, that´s why i asked for it.

Comment: see edit in question

Comment: @PascalAckermann it seems like you are creating a new `testPanel` with each click on the button(which wont have any effect since it´s never shown) rather then working on the existing one. How are you adding it to the `JFrame`? is it stored inside a variable? If yes, just invoke `testPanel#change` on this variable. If not store the `testPanel` in a variable before adding it to the `JFrame` and make use of it.

Comment: see edit, I added how I add the external jPanel class to my jFrame (or jPanel which is on my jFrame).

Comment: @PascalAckermann if you already have an instance of testPanel, why you create a new one? you can call the method `change` on the existed object, which is probably layouted somewhere?

Comment: But I can't call it because it's a `non-static`method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){


    TestPanel panel = new TestPanel();

    JButton button = new JButton();
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         panel.change();
        }

    };

    button.addActionListener(al);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(button);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    frame.setSize(420, 360);



    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



}
```

Or the funnier example with smiley face:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package repaintquestions;

/**
 *
 * @author peter
 */
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public boolean draw = true;

    public TestPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 603, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 299, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw == true) {
            // g.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 35);
        }
        paintSmile(g, draw);
    }

    public void change() {
        draw = !draw;

        this.repaint();

    }

    public void paintSmile(Graphics g, boolean smile) {

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);

        g.fillOval(0, 0, 400, 400);

        g.setColor(Color.black);

        g.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);

        g.fillOval(250, 100, 50, 50);

        g.drawArc(150, 250, 100, 100, 180, 180);

        if (smile) {
            g.drawArc(150, 250, 100, 100, 180, 180);
        } else {
            g.drawArc(150, 250, 100, 100, 0, 180);
        }

      //  repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestPanel panel = new TestPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton();
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.change();
            }

        };

        button.addActionListener(al);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(button);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.setSize(800, 800);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the given edits:

in your `jButton1ActionPerformed` method. Instead of creating a new `testPanel` each time you click the button rather make use of the variable and invoke change on the instance of `testPanel` that is actually shown in your `JFrame`.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    jPanel1.change();
}
```

here is an example how it would work:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    private testPanel panel = new testPanel(); // This is the pane with the line and that is actually visible to you.

    private JPanel underlayingPanel = new JPanel(); // This is the underlaying pane.

    public TestFrame() {

        underlayingPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        underlayingPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //
        JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // This is what you did initially
                //     testPanel panel = new testPanel();
                //     panel.change();
                // The method change is getting executed on the instance of testPanel that is stored inside the variable panel.
                // but the Panel that did get added onto your underlaying panel wont notice this change since it represents another instance
                // of testPanel. In order to make this panel notice the change invoke it on this specific instance
                panel.change();
            }
        });
        underlayingPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setContentPane(underlayingPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `testPanel.change();`? `jPanel1` is just a panel which is under the panel with the line on it.

Comment: If I try with `testPanel.change();` I get an error called: `non-static method change() cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: @PascalAckermann so you have a `testPanel` on a `testPanel` on a `JFrame`? Yeah that´s not possible since `change` is non static, which means it can only be invoked on an instance of `testPanel`. Since your edid suggests that `jPanel1` is an instance of `testPanel`, this should be possible(including that the variable `jPanel1` is also declared to be a `testPanel`). You simply need to store the `testPanel` instance, that is representing the panel with the line in a variable, and once you click the button you invoke the method `change` on this variable.

Comment: I don't really understand, can you please show it on an example, what I have to do in the button method.